# how to get dynamic value of texbox inside gridview which is generated in dropdown selected index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am created dynamic textbox in inside gridview  which is generated in dropdown selected index changed but now i want to save that textbox value in databse but how? there are in one row have Five five dynamic textboxes now how to fetch that value at submit button click at each row Can any one help me

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewclass" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridViewclass_RowDataBound"
    OnDataBound="GridViewclass_DataBound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#174A63" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" AllowPaging="true" Font-Size="14px"
    Style="margin-left: 16%;" PageSize="15" Width="300px">
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedRowStyle" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 4">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

//Code behind

```
protected void ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int createrows = 0;
        int GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassUnits.SelectedValue);
        if (GroupId == 0)
        {
            ClearContentControls(4);
        }
        else
        {
            if (GroupId == 1)
            {
                createrows = 1;
            }
            if (GroupId == 2)
            {
                createrows = 2;
            }

            GridViewclass.Visible = true;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));

            for (int i = 0; i < createrows; i++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["RowNumber"] = i + 1; ;
                dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
                dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
                dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
                dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
                dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            GridViewclass.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewclass.DataBind();
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Now how to fetch that dynamic textbox value in submit button click

Comment: Try enumerating the GridViewclass.Controls collection, maybe checking for objects of type TextBox.

Comment: I cant understand what you say , i m new in this field so...Help